# django formset option value set to none

Tags: django

Gratings Developer,

While working with Django I encounter a problem. Django formset give option value to none.

```
<select name="form-1-model" id="id_form-1-model">
<option value="">---------</option>

<option value="None" selected>option_1</option>

<option value="None">option_2</option>
```

models.py

```
class orderlist(models.Model):
      # product_list.objects.a
      date=models.DateField(auto_created=timezone.now(),auto_now_add=True)
      sr=models.CharField(max_length=50)
      dealer=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=False)
      shopno=models.IntegerField()
      model=models.ForeignKey(product_list,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      quantity=models.IntegerField(default=None)
      def __str__(self):
            return self.model
```

I declare formset like this

```
orderformset=formset_factory(orderform,extra=len(get_all_product),max_num=10)
```

productlist im model form

```
class product_list(models.Model):
      #  d=models.DateField(auto_created=True,auto_now_add=timezone.now())
      deal=models.ForeignKey(DealerForm, null=True,blank=True ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      date=models.DateField(auto_created=True,auto_now_add=timezone.now())
      model=models.ForeignKey(WarehouseUpdateForm,  null=True,default=None,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      quantity=models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
      free=models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True,validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
      def __str__(self):
            return str(self.model)
```

orderform in forms.py

```
class orderform(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = orderlist
            fields= ('model','quantity')
```

Comment: Can you share the `product_list` model and the orderform`?

Comment: I updated it please check

Comment: previously this code was working but now it's not i don't know why, may be i messed up something @IainShelvington

Comment: Can you share the full view and the part of your template where you render this field?

Comment: here is the pastebin link https://pastebin.com/raw/Ey4Vy8aD @IainShelvington

Comment: That's just the rendered output from your view? Add the view and template to the question

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VJRYzXwN views.py file @IainShelvington

Comment: And the template? `order.html`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/Ey4Vy8aD this is order.html @IainShelvington

Comment: That's the rendered template, where's the template before it's rendered? `order.html` must contain some template tags?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cynpm7RS here it is @IainShelvington

Comment: Sorry I have no idea, the only thing I can think is that `product_list.objects.values('pk')` is returning a bunch of Nones instead of ids

Comment: @IainShelvington I appreciate your effort I have a question my option display properly not the value inside html tag. If I am not wrong both value pull from same path to display the result. am I right?

Comment: For a `ModelChoiceField` (the form field for a ForeignKey) to generate the options the queryset is iterated over: the label for each option is the string representation of the instance `str(instance)` and the value is usually the pk/id. Why you are getting None for the value is not clear

Comment: I get value, not None. @IainShelvington
[here] (https://ibb.co/GPYVKb1) your will see product_list in database

Comment: Why do you get `_id` as `ObjectId("...")` for your instances? What database are you using?

Comment: mongo db on local @IainShelvington

Comment: Ahhh, which package are you using to connect to mongodb? Django doesn't really play well with mongodb and whatever package you are using probably has a custom ModelChoiceField that you may have to use

Comment: I have several fromset in my project other works fine. Only this code have problem. BTW it's djongo @IainShelvington

Comment: @IainShelvington I solved it. I created admin account before migrating that's why may be it's not accepting. I delete my database and re-upload it again and it's working fine